# Attach Keyboard/Mouse to X Display in Dell XPS L502x Dual Video Cards (Intel/Nvidia HDMI)

Tags: 12.04, keyboard, mouse, dell, xserver

**The idea:** 
Use a second monitor in Dell XPS L502x with HDMI port in Ubuntu 12.04

**The process:**
I connect the HDMI cable to monitor.

I read [**this**](http://hanynowsky.wordpress.com/2012/04/07/dell-xps-15-l502x-ubuntu-linux/) and I have video in HDMI monitor with Bumblebee and this commands:

```
optirun nvidia-settings -c :8
DISPLAY=:8.0 firefox
```

I have created a second keyboard/mouse master group with xinput with this [**solution**](https://superuser.com/questions/390458/multiple-keyboard-and-mouse-inputs).

**The problem:**
The second monitor (Display 8) doesn't recognize the keyboard/mouse and I cant use it.

**The question:**
Do you know some command to attach the keyboard/mouse master group to Display 8? I think that `xinput -set-cs` may work but it does not.

Answer (score -1):

Hi you could see this post, it works for me , now my hdmi it's working on my xps 15z. http://www.webupd8.org/2012/08/get-hdmi-working-with-nvidia-optimus-on.html
I hope this help you!

Comment: Hi @Edwin, yor answer good look, but my question is for have two separated "virtual computers" in the same laptop. Thanks anyway!